# Optional callback with optional parameter

Tags: dart

I may be doing something wrong syntactically or practically so "don't do that" could be valid but it seems this should work:

```dart
class Thing {
  //static dynamic noop = () { }; // fails
  static dynamic noop = ([dynamic value]) { }; // works for null cases
  dynamic _callback;
  Thing._([dynamic callback([dynamic value])])
    : this._callback = callback != null ? callback : Thing.noop;

  factory Thing([dynamic callback([dynamic value])]) {
    return new Thing._(callback);
  }
}
```

---

*When I run these tests, the first one fails but the second, third and fourth pass:*

```dart
//Caught type '() => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '([dynamic]) => dynamic' of 'callback'.
test('callback with optional param', () {
  var thing = new Thing(() { });
  thing.doCallback();
  thing.doCallback('data');
});

test('callback with optional param', () {
  var thing = new Thing(([_]) { });
  thing.doCallback();
  thing.doCallback('data');
});

test('callback with optional param', () {
  var thing = new Thing();
  thing.doCallback();
  thing.doCallback('data');
});

test('callback with optional param', () {
  var thing = new Thing(null);
  thing.doCallback();
  thing.doCallback('data');
});
```

Comment: Just to follow up, the approach I think will work is changing the signature of Thing to ([dynamic callback(), dynamic onData(dynamic value)]) so that existing consumers can still register callbacks as per usual but new consumers can opt into on data notifications as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic callback([dynamic value])` means a `callback` that can take one parameter or none. In your first test case, the callback you provides (`() { }`) only handles calls with no parameter. So it does not respect the contract. That's why you get this error.

Comment: Yeah, was too focused on trying to avoid breaking changes :P